# DefinitivelyTyped nominatim search result type?

Tags: nominatim, typescript

When I use a query like this:

`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=bakery+in+berlin+wedding&format=json&limit=1`

(from https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/#json-with-address-details)

I am getting some search results.

##### Is there any [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types) type or interface for the search result?

I think that *geojson* is not the right type, since it is the **plain JSON** format. I can build by own interface, but there might already be something right out there in the wild.